# How to invoke a custom method/cleanUp after all tests? (Geb and Spock)

Tags: maven, testing, automated-tests, spock, geb

To set up the environment before running tests I use the GebConfig.groovy class which is triggered as first component when runnig tests. But I also need to restore the environment to the initial state after all tests are finished.

I tried to overwtire the method cleanUpSpec() in class which extended GebReportingSpec class, but it is invoked after each test.

Is there a way to invoke a method after all tests are completed to clean up the environment to the initial state?

I am using maven in this project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any mechanism in Geb or Spock. Generally my experience is that you will be in a better place when every test sets the stage before it starts instead of relying on some cleanup mechanism, which might not have been executed.

However, if you really need this, I'd suggest to use something like  [Maven Exec Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) with execution phase post-(integration-)test:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>cleanup</id>
            <phase>post-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>cleanup.groovy</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can use any executable file instead of `cleanup.groovy` but keep in mind that is has to be executable (`chmod +x ...`).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have some questions:
1. Where this file 'cleanup.groovy' should be stored? On the same level as pom.xml?
2. Should this code you have provided in the answer be placed next to maven-surefire-plugin?
3. I created a file 'cleanup.groovy' with content 'println("All tests have been executed!")' and run one test class, but that line has not been executed.

I don't know if I understood you correctly. Will be grateful for help.

Comment: In this example the `cleanup.groovy` should indeed be next to `pom.xml`. However you can configure any path you like.
There is no need to put it next to surefire. The connection is made by the configured `<phase>`. Using `<phase>post-test</phase>` makes Maven execute right after test phase. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html for more options for phases.

Comment: Note that I updated the source. I used the wrong phase `clean` which will execute during `mvn clean`.

Comment: The problem is that in this project I already had maven-failsafe-plugin and it has <phase>verify</phase>. Here you can see whole plugin https://ibb.co/e5O7Pf I will try to change it to 'post-test' and see what will happen. Cause I guess it was set to verify for some reason

Comment: If you want the script be executed after failsafe, you should use `<phase>post-verify</phase>`.

Comment: Ok I will try to use <phase>post-verify</phase>. I tried with this configuration: https://ibb.co/g5Lwjf and the code has not been executed. Moreover I run tests by clicking play button next to the test class so by JUnit runner. Should I run those tests in another way so this would work?

Comment: This is a pure Maven solution. Running `mvn verify` will take care of the execution. Running the test from the IDE will ignore this.

Comment: Ok. Right now it seems to be clear to me. I will talk to my team and will try to implement this in our project. If I have any problems could I write here to you? Thanks for help by the way.